# My model doesn't work in test dataset

Tags: r

1. I got the data of stomach cancer from TCGA, I found some different
   expression genes between cancer and normal sample.
2. I put aside my normal sample, and divide my cancer sample into
   train(80%) and test(20%) groups.
3. I did Unicox (with survival package), lasso (with glmnet package)
   and multicox ( with survival package) on train group, to find out
   which genes are more related to survival.
4. I use coefficients of each genes (that I got from multicox), to
   built my model and calculate the risk score. Like that: (expression
   of gene1×coefficient gene1 + expression of gene2×coefficient gene2
   +...).
5. I divided my sample in to high risk and low risk groups, to compare
   survival between them, using Kaplan-Meier.

In training group, Kaplan-Meier shows significant difference between high and low risk group. However when I use my model on my test group, it is not significant. Why this problem occurs? I assumed my model is overfit of my train group, but how can I fix it? Why does this happen even when I use lasso?

Comment: Do you have sufficient power? Are your hazard rates/ratios very different between train and test? It would be possible to have a model that performs exactly as well as it did in the training data, but that shows up with no significant difference simply due to having a smaller sample size in the test data.

Comment: Hi, thank u for your answer, yes at first I thought it is because of small sample size in test group, so I tried diving samples, 70-30, 60-40, and even 50-50. In all of the them pvalue in Kaplan meier was <0.001 in train group, and in non of the it was significant in test group

Comment: Hi @FaridehJafari could you kindly format your question to make it clear?

Answer (score 0):

There is no overtraining here, it isn't deep learning and there appears no parameterisation. If parameterisation was occurring on the training set that can and does cause over-tightening.

Essentially, you haven't included a data split for parameterisation, i.e. there is no parameterisation. The theory of a parameterisation is it must be distinct from training (and obviously) testing. It allows parameter tuned without overtightening. Lasso regression will require parameterisation.

I don't know about the survival regressions for machine learning, but lasso/ridge regression are standard approaches.

---

So just to explain, what you do is have a split for parameters. Thus instead of 80:20 split it could be 70:20:10 split where the 10% is used for parameter optimisation. Bad code risks leakage from the parameter split and that can result in over-tightening.